# How do I add collision for armature?

Tags: physics

I have a hair mesh with an armature attached, and am using a plugin called wiggle bones to simulate the physics for moving the hair. However, the problem is the hair goes through my character mesh. I've tried adding collision to the hair mesh, but the the hair still goes through the head of the character.

Comment: so I guess you need to give Cloth or Soft Body to your hair rather than Collision, and give Collision to the head?

Comment: I forgot to mention my hair is low poly, and it would also be great if I could stick with using a bones system, so in the future my models will be compatible with game engines.

I tried adding soft body as a test, and the hair was much more deformed compared to my nice smooth hair I created once the physics started playing through. Also the calculation times for softbody is pretty insane compared to using something like wiggle bones for realtime playback.

Comment: a trick is to give physics to a plane or a cage (a cube that is a bit subdivided), give the cloth simulation to this plane or cage, use it as the object of a Surface or Mesh Deform modifier that you give to your hair mesh, this way Blender need to calculate the physics for a rather simple object, not a lot of vertices

Comment: That is a good trick, i'll have to play with that idea. Thanks!